# How to Sort a String with Number by Ascending

Tags: esp8266, string, array

I have trouble figuring out how to sort a String that has a Number in it.

The String im sending looks like 112:AAAA and 111:EEEE, how would I sort it so that the 111 will be the first in an array but (and here is what I cant figure out) the sorted array should contain the letters again so it would be a String Array that is sorted by the numbers and look like 111:EEEE, 112:AAAA.

I wanted to use what I have seen on C#, having a key and value, but that does not seem to exist in arduino code. So I improvised by writing everything in 1 char array.

edit: I see I'm mixing up char array and string, im very flexible and its no trouble to change to 1 or the other, currently I use char arrays.

I guess it would also be enough to just sort the strings, but i cant find a function for that also.

Comment: Are the numbers always 3-digit long? If so, you can just lexicographically sort the strings.

Comment: They can be 2-3 digit long

Answer (score 2):

As Michel Keijzers points out, `qsort` is the standard sorting function
from the libc. Now, since your numbers can start with either two or
three digits, you can not sort them lexicographically, because if you
did so 111 would sort before 82. Instead I suggest to:

- parse the start of the strings as integers
- compare the integers
- if the integers are equal, then sort the strings lexicographically.

The simplest way to parse the strings into integers is `atoi()`. Unlike
functions like `strtol()`, `atoi()` does no error checking, but it is
good enough if you know for sure that the strings have the right format.

Here is the comparison function:

```cpp
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    // Get the strings.
    const char *sa = *(const char * const *) a;
    const char *sb = *(const char * const *) b;

    // First, compare the numeric prefixes.
    int ia = atoi(sa);
    int ib = atoi(sb);
    if (ia < ib) return -1;
    if (ia > ib) return +1;

    // If equal, compare the strings lexicographically.
    return strcmp(sa, sb);
}
```

And here is an example on how to use it:

```cpp
#define STR_COUNT 3
const char *strings[STR_COUNT] = { "112:AAAA", "82:FFFF", "111:EEEE" };
qsort(strings, STR_COUNT, sizeof strings[0], compare);
```

Now the array of strings is sorted as ("82:FFFF", "111:EEEE",
"112:AAAA").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `qsort` function (see [c-library-function-to-do-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787996/c-library-function-to-do-sort)).

With the user definable `comp` function you can get the first two or three characters, convert it to in integer and compare it against the converted integer from another element.

I would not advise to use strings, because of the limited SRAM storage of an Arduino, you might run out of memory too fast.